# Angular global styles not applied to copied components

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I am busy combining my groups code for a large project we have and came across a strange issue.

So far when I copied everyone's component files over and served the styles were applied just fine (Using Gradus theme)

But one team members components are not accepting the styles at all. i copied it over the same way and he created them in gradus as well. All buttons are the basic buttons. It seems that not even material is applied to them. Even If I copy elements from working files they are still un styled and non-material.

Anything that I can look out for?

Comment: check if the component has replaced the global classes with different styles. Or inline styles. css  [Styling Priorities](https://www.thebookdesigner.com/2017/02/styling-priorities-css-for-ebooks-3/)

Comment: Check what is set on component attribute ViewEncapsulation. you may find  what it is here https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation.  And also if this component is injected in runtime you may have to use :host ::ng-deep with css classes to get the actual class of those dom elements.